# How to add multithreading in Selenium Python when using url range?

Tags: python, selenium, python-multithreading

So my thoughts are that if I would add something that can split the url-range into 5 and then give each of 5 chromedriver instances their own split of the url-range to handle it would make scraping much faster. And thats my biggest question. But maybe then its better if each chromedriver had their own csv file, or I would need to add something that pools all the scraping in one file? Im really at a loss here and I'm already pushing my skill level. I am eternally grateful for any concrete help on at least how to get multithreading working. Thank you!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import csv
path_to_file = "test1.csv"
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
header_added = False
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(1,153512):
    print(f"https://www.ancestry.com/discoveryui-content/view/{i}:61965")
    driver.get(f"https://www.ancestry.com/discoveryui-content/view/{i}:61965")
    try:
        Name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='recordServiceData']//tr[contains(.,'Name:')]").text.replace("Name:", "")
    except:
        Name =''
    csvWriter.writerow([i, Name])
    print(Name)
```

Comment: can you please help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181276/how-to-add-multithreading-in-selenium-python-when-using-for-fetch-data-from-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import csv
path_to_file = "test1.csv"
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

header_added = False
time.sleep(3)


    
def init_driver_worker(_range_task): #create new instace of chrome then make it do its job
    ##### init driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #you can't run multible instances of chrome
    #  with the same profile being used,
    #  so either create new profile for each instance or use incognito mode
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("--headless") #use headless browser (no GUI) to be faster
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    ##### do the task
    for i in _range_task:
        print(f"https://www.ancestry.com/discoveryui-content/view/{i}:61965")
        driver.get(f"https://www.ancestry.com/discoveryui-content/view/{i}:61965")
        try:
            Name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='recordServiceData']//tr[contains(.,'Name:')]").text.replace("Name:", "")
        except:
            Name =''
        csvWriter.writerow([i, Name])
        print(Name)
    exit() #close the thread
    
    
    
def split_range(_range, parts): #split a range to chunks
    chunk_size = int(len(_range)/parts)
    chunks = [_range[x:x+chunk_size] for x in range(0, len(_range), chunk_size)]
    return chunks

my_range = range(1,153512)
chunks = split_range(my_range, 10) # split the task to 10 instances of chrome

from threading import Thread
thread_workers = []
for chunk in chunks:
    t = Thread(target=init_driver_worker, args=([chunk]))
    thread_workers.append(t)
    t.start()
    
# wait for the thread_workers to finish
for t in thread_workers:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Hello Ibrahem! Thank you for such a quick answer. I just tried it but I get an error: Exception in thread Thread-1 (init_driver_worker):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-2 (init_driver_worker):
For more: https://pastebin.com/Zkp13wdu

Comment: Comment: I found the answer to the first comment. you had just one mistake in the code, one missing comma: args=(chunk)) should be args=(chunk,))

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested the code first. I fixed it using args=([chunk]). also, I added options.add_argument("--headless")  to use headless browser (no GUI)  for the code to be faster and lighter (&& thanks for your vote Up !)