# How to add multithreading in Selenium Python when using for fetch data from file.?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I want to  add something that can split the task  into 5 and then give each of 5 chromedriver instances their own split of t to handle it would make automation much faster. And thats my biggest question. But maybe then its better if each chromedriver had their own csv file, or I would need to add something that pools all the scraping in one file? Im really at a loss here and I'm already pushing my skill level. I am eternally grateful for any concrete help on at least how to get multithreading working. Thank you!

each threads should take next cell data wihtout repeating previous one , And each threads should take unique data at a time.

```
import openpyxl
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from threading import Thread
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

def pass_data(url,driver , num):

    driver.header_overrides = {
        'USER-AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G981B) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    }
    
    #time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(url)
    print("URL Called")
    try:

        WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wikipedia-search-input'))).send_keys(num)
        time.sleep(3)

    except WebDriverException as exception:
        print("Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited")
    #time.sleep(2)
    #driver.close()

def header_val():
    urls = "https://testautomationpractice.blogspot.com/"
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.active
    m_row = sheet.max_row
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=m_row, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
        pass_data(urls,cell.value,driver)
header_val()
```

Comment: Did you think in Selenium Grid? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/

Comment: No not like that ... In normal case we can run a selenium web driver and pass any data through its (send.keys(data)) .... I want to a script that creates multi threading and can run a multi we drive to pass a data from excel or txt .. Each threads will have a new data without repeating others threads data.